# How can PHP retrieve formData from reactJS

Tags: php, reactjs

At the frontend the POST request is sent like this:

```
fetch("/api/login.php", 
  { credentials: 'same-origin', 
    method: 'POST', 
    body: formData,
  }
)
```

formData includes a string and a file, which is defined like this:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('name', field1.value);
formData.append('file', field2.files[0]);
```

Does anyone know how to retrieve "name"(string) and "file"(object) in login.php?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: If your variables aren't showing up in the `$_POST` array, they may be in the standard input - try `$mydata=file_get_contents("php://input");` and printing the `$mydata` variable

Answer (score 0):

```
$variable  = $_POST['name'];
$file_Name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
```